How to disable BackingStore and dirty tracking in Graph Beta SDK for Java
When profiling my Kotlin application using the latest Java Graph Beta SDK (v6.6.0 as we speak), I saw that most of the time was "lost" doing some dirty tracking inside the backingStore.
Functions like ensureCollectionPropertyIsConsistent are taking 99% of my call graph ATM 
I am only doing GET requests in my project so I definitely don't need this feature.
Is there any easy way to disable the backingStore completely ?

Please copy your code as text in the question.

This is not my code but library code

I'm afraid that SDK is generated with backing store feature enabled by default and it' can be disabled. Better to ask directly in SDK GitHub repo: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues

I went further to engage the relevant team on this and hence sharing this update. The workaround is to disable the backing store can only be done during the client generation. Microsoft Graph Java SDK uses Kiota on its generation. Since you are only working on GET operations, the suggestion is for you to generate your won library, with only the endpoints you care about for use.
Here is how you can generate a self-serve SDK and leverage it in their solution.
To generate a client library with no backing store using Kiota CLI, it would be something like the following:

kiota generate --openapi https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-metadata/master/openapi/beta/openapi.yaml --language java --output app/src/main/java/meclient/apiclient --class-name GraphBaseServiceClient --namespace-name meclient.apiclient --include-path '/me/**
The --include-path parameter is responsible for filtering the current OpenAPI document and match all endpoints with what was provided, so they should use it to match/describe the endpoints they need.
Here are some more details on all parameter available: Using the Kiota tool | Microsoft Learn
Microsoft also provides a Kiota Visual Studio Code Extension, so one can use it to also generate their client.


This will load the OpenAPI explorer with all endpoints available (and all pre-selected). They can click on "remove all" and just select the endpoints they need.

Then hit generate.

The extension will ask for some additional information, like class name, namespace, output directory and the chosen language and it will create the API client with no backing store capability. I hope this will be helpful but feel free to reach out on the thread should you have further questions.

Thanks, that's what I thought. I'll try to bootstrap a minimum code example for the team and let them see what's wrong with it by opening an issue on the repo

@rak007- I went further to engage the relevant team on this and got a work around which I am updating in the answer section.

Thank @CarolM, it is the route that we took and generated our own Kiota version without the backingStore and very specific endpoints.
The generated version is still not as performant as the "pre-Kiota generation version" we were using before like com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph-beta - 0.74.
Team is crafting a minimum reproductible example to showcase performance drop and we will post an issue on the repository soon.
